# How can I evaluate this summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, mellin-transform

How can I evaluate this summation?\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\,?\end{align}I have\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{2m-1}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}=\frac{B_{2m}}{4m}\end{align}for odd m>1... or do I have to use mellin transform?

Comment: Looks like: $-\frac{\pi }{12}-\ln \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{2 \pi ^{3/4}}\right)$. Solved with CAS like `Mathematica`.

Comment: oh thanks..but how?

Comment: Maybe this is a start to search for related topics on this site: http://www.linas.org/math/plouffe-ram.pdf

Comment: General term can be written as $$\frac{\coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}$$

Comment: If we expand $1/(e^{2 \pi n} - 1)$ into series and change the order of summation, we get $-\ln \phi(e^{-2 \pi})$, where $\phi(q) = (q; q)_\infty$ is the Euler function. The value of $\phi(e^{-2 \pi})$ was found by Ramanujan. See Berndt, *Ramanujan's Notebooks*, Vol. 3 for a proof.